# Jquery-file-upload exif extract and submit additional form data

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload

I want to get GPS info to server-side.
I try something like this, and is not working:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    change: function (e, data) {
        $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
            EXIF.getData(file, function() {
                // alert(EXIF.pretty(this));
                var long = EXIF.getTag(this, 'GPSLongitude');
                var longDecimal = toDecimal(long);
                $("#longDecimal["+index+"]").val(longDecimal);
            });              
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: what is this EXIF library you are using?

Comment: The EXIF library I`m using is https://github.com/exif-js/exif-js